# Need div to hover and then to go to other page with two touchs on ipad/iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

If you could help me ive been having a problem with touch on ipad/iphone for my hover rollover href link.

I'd like my box to hover to an image on the first touch on the ipad, then be able to touch again to send the user to another page. Currently the link wont show. And im struggling to know what to do.

HTML:

```
<!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
<div class="image-container">
   <div class="image-container-overflow">
      <div class="image-container-actual">
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
            <div class="hoverimg">
               <a href="success.html">
                  <img class="fade" src="_includes/img/global/image2.jpg" width="188" height="188" />
                  <p>Helen was offered a job as a florist two weeks after she completed her Pinewood training. <br><br><strong>See Success Stories</strong></p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
```

CSS:-

```
/* Editable Multiple Image Area */
.image-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.internal .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contact .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container-overflow {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 187px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}

.image-container-actual {
    width: 100%;
    height: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 188px;
    height: 188px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.image img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.image:hover div {
    display: block!important;
}

.image img:hover div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f28f0a;
}

.hoverimg {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f28f0a;
}

.hoverimg p {
    font-family: 'ralewayregular';
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/m67k8/

If anyone has an idea i would gratefully appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JavaScript/JQuery to do that. The clicked (touched) link needs to act differently whether the hover content is shown or not, so I think the quickest and simplest way would be to add a class on the .hoverimg when it's on, then write a function with a condition to control the behaviour of the link like this :

```
$('.hoverimg a').click(function(e) {
    if ( !$(this).parent('.hoverimg').hasClass('on') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.hoverimg').addClass('on').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m67k8/1/